If $\mathbf{M}$ is a transitive proper class model of $\sf{ZF}-\sf{P}$, then $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{L}^{\mathbf{L}} \subset \mathbf{M}$.
In Kunen's "Set Theory An Introduction To Independence Proofs", we are given the following (where $\mathbf{L}$ is Gödels constructible universe, I think it is called):

Theorem: If $\mathbf{M}$ is a transitive proper class model of $\sf{ZF}-\sf{P}$, then $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{L}^{\mathbf{L}} \subset \mathbf{M}$.

The proof goes like this (parahprased, with added comments):

We first note that $\mathbf{ON} \subset \mathbf{M}$. To see this, fix $\alpha \in \mathbf{ON}$. Since $\mathbf{M} \not \subset R(\alpha)$, there is an $x \in \mathbf{M}$ with $\mathrm{rank}(x) \geq \alpha$. But the rank function is absolute for $\mathbf{M}$, so $\mathrm{rank}(x) \in \mathbf{M}\rightarrow \alpha \in \mathbf{M}$ (by transitivity of $\mathbf{M}$). Now, by absoluteness of $L(\alpha)$ (and $\mathbf{ON}$), $$\mathbf{L}^{\mathbf{M}} = \{x \in \mathbf{M}: (\exists \alpha(x \in L(\alpha)))^{\mathbf{M}}\} = \bigcup \{L(\alpha): \alpha \in \mathbf{ON}\},$$ so $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{L}^{\mathbf{M}} \subset \mathbf{M}$.

Now, I follow the proof until the last step with the equalities above, and I think I understand (sort of) the first equality. But I don't understand the last equality. Since we know that $L(-)$ is absolute for $\mathbf{M}$, this means that $L(-):\mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{V}$ regarded as a function, is such that $L(-)^{\mathbf{M}}:\mathbf{M} \to \mathbf{M}$ so that $L(-)^{\mathbf{M}} = L(-) \upharpoonright \mathbf{M}$. So, we know that $\mathbf{ON} \subset \mathbf{M}$, which means that $L(\alpha)$ is the same in $\mathbf{M}$ as in $\mathbf{V}$, I presume, from which it follows that $\mathbf{L}$ must be the same in $\mathbf{M}$ as in $\mathbf{V}$ (by definition of $\mathbf{L}$) , so that $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{L}^{\mathbf{M}} \subset \mathbf{M}$?
Is my understanding correct? Basically, for class-functions $F$(see $\S5$ in chapter IV of Kunen), what $F:\mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{V}$ being absolute for a class $\mathbf{M}$ means is that $\mathbf{F}^{\mathbf{M}} = \mathbf{F} \upharpoonright \mathbf{M}$. It seems like this together with the fact that $\mathbf{ON} \subset \mathbf{M}$ and the definition of $\mathbf{L}$ as $\mathbf{L} = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbf{ON}} L(\alpha)$ gives us what we want.

I think your understanding is correct.
First off, $\bf M$ satisfying $\sf ZF-P$ implies the function $\alpha\mapsto L(\alpha)$ is definable in $\bf M,$ which means it makes sense to talk about the function relative to $\bf M$ and its absoluteness. It is absolute for transitive models, as Kunen shows, so this implies, as you say, that the function relative to $\bf M$ is just the restriction to $\bf M$. And since $\bf M$ contains all the ordinals, $L(\alpha)=L^{\mathbf M}(\alpha)\in \bf M$ for all $\alpha\in\bf ON.$

Great, thanks, as always, for the feedback. =)

Just a quick clarification; do you mean that because $\mathbf{M}$ satisfies $\sf{ZF}-\sf{P}$, comprehension holds in $\mathbf{M}$, and therefore it makes sense to talk about it in $\mathbf{M}$? Or I presume that  by definable you (informally) mean that we can $\mathbf{M}$ can represent $\alpha \mapsto L(\alpha)$ internally? Ofc it has to be able to represent ordinals as well (which it can, just pointing it out).

@Ben123 I mean $\forall \alpha\in\mathbf{ON};\exists !y;y = L(\alpha)$ can be proven relative to $\bf M$. (And really that the entire theory up to that point can be developed... $y=L(\alpha)$ being a somewhat complicated definition.)
